# can someone please explain to me the reason and the logic behind this output?

Tags: c++, constructor, logic, function-signature

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
    int i;
public:
    A(int i) : i(i) { cout << i << endl; }
    A(const A &o) : i(o.i) { cout << i << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << i << endl; }
    friend A f(const A &, A, A *);
};
A f(const A &a, A b, A *c) { return *c; }
int main() { 
    f(1, A(2), &A(3));
}
```

**output : 1 3 2 3 2 3 3 1**
can someone please help me understand the reason behind the sequence of this output?

Comment: You have undefined behviour (taking the address of a temporary object `&A(3)`, and then also dereferencing `c`, which is a dangling pointer in `f`) Better fix that first to avoid confusion.

Comment: Taking the address of a temporary is undefined behaviour. Also, the evaluation of function parameters is unspecified behaviour. So this entire question is pretty flawed.

Comment: Well this is not really usefull, maybe create 3 objects that print differents symbols, so we can differenciate the three.

Comment: Is the intention to understand the construction order of the `A` objects when calling the function `f`?

Comment: yes! the intention is to understand the construction order of A.    
it is a question from an exam that i am having tomorrow..

Comment: Your **compiler** not [telling](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e453fef1aa871ba) [you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64a87a94ef04bfa8) [anything](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08a177546c409ec6) ? :P

Comment: The evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified. But with undefined behaviour, anything goes, so the question is unanswerable unless you fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the evaluation of the function arguments is not defined; they can constructed in any order.

As a demonstration of this, here is some empirical evidence of this.

I've made minor modifications to print the output on a single line, also showing the construction `ctor`, copy construction `copy` and destruction `dtor` of each `A` and removing the undefined behaviour of caused by the use of `&A(3)`.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
    int i;
public:
    A(int i) : i(i) { cout << "ctor" << i << " "; }
    A(const A &o) : i(o.i) { cout << "copy" << i << " "; }
    ~A() { cout << "dtor" << i << " "; }
    friend A f(const A &, A, A *);
};
void f(const A &a, A b, A&& c) { ; }
int main() { 
    f(1, A(2), A(3));
}
```

Using GCC 4.9, I get `ctor3 ctor2 ctor1 dtor1 dtor2 dtor3`.

Using MSVC 2013.2, I get `ctor1 ctor3 ctor2 dtor2 dtor3 dtor1`.

---

As an aside; IRC, the order in which they are destructed is the reverse of the order in which they are constructed.